# How to copy list permission to another list

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I tried to use Import-SPWeb with option -IncludeUserSecurity but it doesn't import permissions. Do you know any Powershell script that I can use copy list permission to another list?

Answer (score 2):

As per MSDN, "IncludeUserSecurity" - Preserves the user security settings except for SPLists that have broken inheritance and item level permissions set. So list level permission will not be inherited.

Reference : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: Info: In our case there was one problem with "IncludeUserSecurity". A user that has been deleted from the site collection (flag tp_isActive = 0 in dbo.userinfo table in the content database) has been activated again.